# array value inside <> can't be shown

Tags: php

i have a file txt1111.txt

inside the file:

```
000 DR name=<pppoe-532@hd> rx-byte=2729155 tx-byte=25761627 rx-packet=21263 tx-packet=24445

001 DR name=<pppoe-567@hd> rx-byte=4499997 tx-byte=98614277 rx-packet=58601 tx-packet=76057

002 DR name=<pppoe-600@hd> rx-byte=1354279 tx-byte=32875565 rx-packet=22148 tx-packet=30756
```

my php code is:

```
 $array = explode("\n", file_get_contents('txt1111.txt'));

 echo "<pre/>";print_r($array);
```

the output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 000 DR name= rx-byte=2729155 tx-byte=25761627 rx-packet=21263 tx-packet=24445
    [1] => 001 DR name= rx-byte=4499997 tx-byte=98614277 rx-packet=58601 tx-packet=76057
    [2] => 002 DR name= rx-byte=1354279 tx-byte=32875565 rx-packet=22148 tx-packet=30756
)
```

my question is why the name values are empty as they shown on output?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this using htmlentities() :

```
 $array = explode("\n", htmlentities(file_get_contents('txt1111.txt')));

 echo "<pre/>";print_r($array);
```

Comment: thanks dear @mith  it works. but i want <> to be removed .. what is want is the name only? any advice?

Comment: You can use       preg_replace('~[<>]~', '', file_get_contents('txt1111.txt')); to remove <> from output string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to those name value then you need to add example:

```
000 DR name=pppoe-532@hd rx-byte=2729155 tx-byte=25761627 rx-packet=21263 tx-packet=24445
```

simple without the <>.
else:

```
000 DR name=<'pppoe-532@hd'> rx-byte=2729155 tx-byte=25761627 rx-packet=21263 tx-packet=24445
```